# Reactivating held users to active via import not working?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am trying to do a mass import to update held users in our system per these instructions: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268698&type=1

While I can change users to "unsubscribed" (steps 9 & 10), when I try changing to "active" (steps 10 & 11), the users return to the "held" status. Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution?

I should note, that I export multiple fields: Email Address, Subscriber Key, Status and Promo Key. We have to keep promo key as this is the only way to connect users to particular titles within our business.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a good idea to change the status of your subscribers from `Held` to `Active` as it can hurt your deliverability. `Held` status means that the address is undeliverable.

> It is not recommended to re-activate previously hard bounced subscribers.

If you can easily identify that they are in `held` status because of soft bounces, then you can re-import as active in Automation Studio:

1. Data Extract of All Subscribers
2. Update the `Held` status to `Active`
3. Import into a Data Extension
4. Data Extract of that Data Extension
5. File Transfer
6. Import to All Subscribers

You can skip steps 1-5 and also just manually Import into All Subs if you don't need to verify counts in a DE first.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232328&type=1